# Finding the adjoint of linear map with respect to an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification, inner-products

Consider the map $A:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $A\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right)=\left(2 x_{1}, x_{1}-x_{2}\right)$. I want to find the adjoint with respect to the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My attempt:
$$\langle A x, y\rangle=\left\langle\left(2 x_{1}, x_{1}-x_{2}\right),\left(y_{1}, y_{2}\right)\right\rangle=2 x_{1} \bar{y}_{1}+\left(x_{1}-x_{2}\right) \bar{y}_{2}$$
And since we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\langle A x, y\rangle=\left\langle x, A^{*} y\right\rangle$ we can write:
$$\begin{array}{l}
2 x_{1} y_{1}+\left(x_{1}-x_{2}\right) y_{2}=\left\langle\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right), A^{*}\left(y_{1}, y_{2}\right)\right\rangle \\
\Rightarrow A^{*}\left(y_{1}, y_{2}\right)=\left(2 y_{1}+y_{2},-y_{2}\right)
\end{array}$$

Can someone confirm if I am correct?

Comment: Why $\bar y$ in the first equation?

Comment: Don't we have $\langle x, y\rangle=\sum_{i} x_{i} \bar{y}_{i}$ in the general case?

Comment: Well here you are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it seems to me a redundant notation. (There's a trivial isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and it's dual).
Anyway if you want to use such a notation then you should have $\bar y$ in the LHS of the second equation.

Comment: When I wrote "since we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$" I was referring to the fact that $\bar{y}=y$. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a linear map $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, the adjoint is just the transpose.

So if

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

you get 
$$A^\star = \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\,.$$

Your answer is correct.